# Insert image from URL

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

The following code works fine with most image URL's, but for this specific URL I am getting errors:

```
Sub test()
Sheets(1).Shapes.AddPicture "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzVlY2JiODctNGMzNC00OWE5LTg3MTEtNDQ3NDYxNjIxNTBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTM3MDMyMDQ@._V1_.jpg" _
                          , msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, 500, 600
End Sub
```

> Run-time error '1004': The specified file wasn't found

Is it caused by the way this specific URL string is specified (not compatible with VBA)? Or do you think it has something to do with the host blocking access? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that they (Amazon) are restricting access to it, treating it like you are "hotlinking" to their image, thus "stealing their bandwidth" - If you looped that code you would be disrupting their servers. Have other pictures from the same server worked for you?

Comment: Thanks, I don't think this is the case as the following URL from same server work's fine: (https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/411nUnjz9eL._SX355_.jpg) with the above code. I suspect it has something to do with the last part of my string in the required URL, specifically; "MDQ@._V1_.jpg" not being compatible, although I could be wrong.

Comment: I tried that URL with your code and have the same error as the other image.

Comment: That's strange, as it works fine even on a fresh instance of Excel for me. What's even more strange is that, if I manually follow the process without VBA for the initial URL (Click insert picture -> specify original url -> click open) it works fine! So seems to be entirely VBA related.

Comment: It could be that you need to encode the characters: `https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzVlY2JiODctNGMzNC00OWE5LTg3MTEtNDQ3NDYxNjIxNTBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTM3MDMyMDQ%40._V1_.jpg`

Comment: @FlorentB. thanks for your suggestion. Just tried this and now get a 'run time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error'. I guess this is due to the url leading to a 404 page - as I get the same error when purposely specifying a URL to a 404 page.

Comment: Ok...this is very strange. Now that exact code which previously didn't work in OP, is working fine for that specific URL, but none of the other similar URL's from the same host in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look for a `*.png` pictures. Then it would work.

I have tried with one from the same Amazon website in PNG -

```
Sub Test()

     Sheets(1).Shapes.AddPicture _
                 "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31TN1u5GEqL.png",  _
                 msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, 500, 600
End Sub
```

In [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-addpicture-method-excel) they give example with `*.bmp` file.

Edit: 
However, `*.jpg` works from plenty of other websites. Thus probably Amazon is restricting it.

Comment: Thanks, it's strange as the following URL from same host seems to work fine as jpg (https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/411nUnjz9eL._SX355_.jpg). 
I guess either amazon are restricting certain URL's, or the problem is to do with that specific string structure not being compatible with VBA.

Comment: @ExamOrph - quite strange indeed. It may be due to the `@` symbol. You can kindly ask their support, but in general they do not like it being crawled - https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2723828  However, they have API, that everyone can use :)

Comment: thanks, upon further review, I am almost certain it is VBA related. As per the above comments on OP, I can manually insert the picture using the original URL fine, but the errors occur only when using VBA to replicate this. I will continue investigating and see where it leads me! Thanks again.