# Code does not Extract the Images from some URL

Tags: excel, vba, image, url, extract

I have been using this code which works for some URL but not for all I really do not why. Then I have tried with different available codes online but no success.

Your help will be really appreciated in this regards.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Filename As String
    
Sub URLPictureInsert()
    Dim theShape As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3000")   ' <---- ADJUST THIS
    For Each cell In rng
        Filename = cell
        If InStr(UCase(Filename), "JPG") > 0 Then   ' <--- USES JPG ONLY
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Filename).Select
            Set theShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
            If theShape Is Nothing Then GoTo isnill
            xCol = cell.Column + 1
            Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
            With theShape
                .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .Width = 20
                .Height = 20
                .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
                .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
            End With
    isnill:
            Set theShape = Nothing
            Range("A2").Select
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Done " & Now

End Sub
```

**URL's**

```vb
    https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/a93f20bbb3640a1a7dc9b9a05bee8540/fc310885-cd82-49cb-bc7a-aabd08531517.jpg
    https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/a93f20bbb3640a1a7dc9b9a05bee8540/c6c7a645-8273-40ee-87e5-1dd385111a28.jpg
    https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/a93f20bbb3640a1a7dc9b9a05bee8540/cf9f971b-6af6-4894-a2d5-c58681adb466.jpg
```

Comment: Are you sure all URLs are valid? The second one gives me a 403...

Comment: Yes there some which having problem but those which are valid should work.

Comment: Remove that `On Error Resume Next` then see if there's any error when you run it.

Comment: Yes an error is appear `Unable to get the insert property of the picture class`

Comment: @Valiant Keep that `On Error Resume Next` removed, it's not going to help you get things right unless you know what you are doing with it. Can you provide the URL that trigger this error?

Comment: Alright i understand! Here it is `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/a93f20bbb3640a1a7dc9b9a05bee8540/55664074-8ebf-4308-8945-0799b1de7e37.jpg` But code should go for next if any URL gives error.

Comment: @Valiant This new link gave the same error as the 2nd link, so you want to skip it if there's an error which is exactly what you described in your question? (if you retain `On Error Resume Next`)

Comment: This error is appear even if i try with working URL `Unable to get the insert property of the picture class` on the line `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Filename).Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below, it will `Debug.Print` the URL that fails to insert. Adapt to your need (if any)

```
Sub URLPictureInsert()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)   ' <---- ADJUST THIS
    End With
    
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If InStr(UCase(cell), "JPG") > 0 Then   '<--- ONLY USES JPG'S
            
            With cell.Offset(0, 1)
                On Error Resume Next
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture cell, msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left + (.Width - 10) / 2, .Top + (.Height - 10) / 2, 20, 20
                If Err.Number = 1004 Then Debug.Print "File not found: " & cell
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
            
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print "Done " & Now
End Sub
```

Comment: No its still not working i have attached a workbook where you can see the result: [Link to File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VHN8LeHriYdSd9keWWNtQbWq4XFeKLxm/view?usp=sharing) @Raymond Wu

Comment: My code works fine (although the macro in the file isn't even my answer), your range is wrong though, it should start from `A2`. I have edited my code to a working one. Please try again with the edited code.

Comment: Yes i tried with your code as well but it give result for those URL whom i was getting earlier with my above code. But why the result no comes from Row12 to onward @Raymond Wu

Comment: I have tried it again and it does works, there are tons of links after row 12 (about half of them?) that is invalid though so those images are not inserted. Try converting the link to actual hyperlink and click it. If Excel can open it then it should insert the image.

Comment: I have updated the file (which link is available above)  with those URL which have images which can be open by clicking on link. But still first 5 or 6 URL's image are display in Col"B"

Comment: @Valiant I just tried your updated file and all the links work, I can see all 21 images in Column B. I'm not sure how to further advise you, possibly some network issue? Just to be sure: 1) In the VBE, Insert a Module (Insert -> Module); 2) Paste the above code in the newly created Module; 3) Run `URLPictureInsert` Sub.

Comment: I really do not understand what is wrong at my end you can see in this gif https://ibb.co/XySVdpK I following completely your instructions but no success

Comment: @Valiant it seems that all the links to amazonaws server are not working, perhaps its an network issue, try again on another network and/or computer and see if it works. Post a new question and see if anyone knows the reason to it.

Comment: Alright i will share feedback thank you very much for being so kind.

Comment: @Valiant a quick google search shows you are not alone on this. You might be blocked by amazon for accessing the images (as spam/? Not sure) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343008/insert-image-from-url

Comment: Yes it could be the only reason Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `On Error Resume Next`, but only for the single statement that inserts the picture. And you should get rid of the `Select`. The `Pictures.Insert`-method returns the reference to the inserted image, assign this to a variable and work with that.

Additionally, I would suggest to split your code and create a routine that insert *one* image into a cell. Call this routine from the loop. I have implemented it as a function that returns `True` if it was successfull, it's up to you to decide if you want to do something if it returns `False`.

```
Function TryInsertImg(filename As String, cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim p As Picture
    On Error Resume Next
    Set p = cell.Parent.Pictures.Insert(filename)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Debug.Print "Couldn't insert image " & Err.Number & "-" & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    If p Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If
        
    Dim theShape As Shape
    Set theShape = p.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    
    With theShape
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width = 20
        .Height = 20
        .Top = cell.Top + (cell.Height - .Height) / 2
        .Left = cell.Left + (cell.Width - .Width) / 2
    End With
    TryInsertImg = True
End Function
```

Your calling routine could look like this:

```
For Each cell In rng
    Filename = cell
    If InStr(UCase(Filename), "JPG") > 0 Then   '<--- ONLY USES JPG'S
        xCol = cell.Column + 1
        Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
        If Not TryInsertImg(filename, xRg) then 
            xRg = "(error loading image)"
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: I tried with your code but i think i am unable to making the filename reference can you please look into the attached file if it does not bother you. [File Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VHN8LeHriYdSd9keWWNtQbWq4XFeKLxm/view?usp=sharing) @FunThomas

Comment: can you please add the range to code because i have been receiving an error https://ibb.co/0QCbxJp can you please look into the attached file